# A CONCATENATED INSERT wont accept a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, insert

This has me seriously stumped. I have a MySQL stored procedure that looks like this.

```
 DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `lms`.`leads_to_bak` ()
BEGIN
SET @table1 = (SELECT `tabler_name` FROM `sets` WHERE `on_off`=0 LIMIT 1);
SET @table2 = CONCAT(@table1, '_bak');
SET @SQL1 = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@table2, '(', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'lead_id,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table2), ')', ' SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'lead_id,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table1), ' FROM ', @table1);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql1;
EXECUTE stmt;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Now the part that is important is this:**

```
SET @SQL1 = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@table2, '(', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'lead_id,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table2), ')', ' SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'lead_id,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table1), ' FROM ', @table1);
```

Now from the looks of it, the statement can be translated to

`INSERT INTO @table2 (col1, col2, col3, ...)[minus lead_id] SELECT (col1, col2, col3, ...)[minus lead_id] FROM @table1`

Pretty simple right? Well I am trying to attach a `WHERE` clause at the end the end of that there `INSERT` statement to make it look something like this:

`INSERT INTO @table2 (col1, col2, col3, ...) SELECT (col1, col2, col3, ...) FROM @table1 WHERE set_id = (SELECT set_id FROM sets WHERE on_off = 0);`

**But no dice. Errors galore. Heck I even tried:**

`INSERT INTO (col1, col2, col3, ...) SELECT (col1, col2, col3, ...) FROM @table1 WHERE set_id = 1;`

**The string output is:**

`INSERT INTO leads_auto_bak(set_id,new_old,upload_date,agent,vendors,callcenter,generation_date,first_name,last_name,email,phone,address,city,state,zip,dob,gender,marital_status,rented,year,make,model,trim,vin,primary_use,miles_oneway,mileage,license_num,license_state,education,job_title,license_status) SELECT set_id,new_old,upload_date,agent,vendors,callcenter,generation_date,first_name,last_name,email,phone,address,city,state,zip,dob,gender,marital_status,rented,year,make,model,trim,vin,primary_use,miles_oneway,mileage,license_num,license_state,education,job_title,license_status FROM leads_auto`

But still nothing. I played around with the different ways to `CONCAT` that line at the end but it wont budge. Anyone got some advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a table name to insert into:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM @table1 
WHERE ...
```

Also, notice there should be no brackets around the columns in your `SELECT` clause.

Comment: That is just a typo. But notice I have the table name in the script itself. The errors I get is with `SET @SQL1 = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@table2, '(', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'lead_id,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table2), ')', ' SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'lead_id,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table1), ' FROM ', @table1);` which has a table name. The brackets are there on purpose so I can convey what is going on. Please only pay attention to the original code for completeness.

Comment: Can you provide the *actual* output of your string concatenation?

Comment: Now there's something I don't know how to do. How do I return a concat'ed string of statements?

Comment: You can just `SELECT @SQL1` and it should return the statement.